# How to get same state of jar to multiple nbm modules?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, maven-nbm

My NetBeans platform application has two **nbm** modules A and B and one **jar** project.
NB modules have a dependency on a JAR which contains singleton class named Engine.
When I access Engine class from module A, Engine object created and returned. So I expect already created Engine object when I call same Engine class from module B.
But it creates new Engine object again and return.

===jar module===

```
Class Engine
{
private static Engine single_instance= null;
private Engine(){}

public static Engine getInstance() 
    { 
        if (single_instance == null) 
{
            single_instance = new Singleton(); 
  }
        return single_instance; 
    }
```

===module A===

```
System.out.println(Engine.getInstance());// prints object address 1
```

===module B===

```
System.out.println(Engine.getInstance());// prints object address 2
```

I want to get same object from module B call as well since jar is shared resource among those two modules.
What is the correct way of sharing the objects between two nbm s via single jar?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement Engine as a ServiceProvider like UpperCaseFilter and then use Lookup in next module to get the implementation.

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html